# C++: function that works with container and container of pointers as well

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, prototype, function-prototypes

I think I'm facing something that I imagine is a quite common problem here.
I'd like to write a function that would be able to accept both a container (let's say `std::vector`) of objects, and a container of pointers to those objects.

What would be the proper way to do so?

Right now, I'm thinking

```cpp
int sum(std::vector<int *> v)
{
  int s = 0;
  for (int * i : v) s += *i;
  return s;
}

int sum(std::vector<int> v)
{
  std::vector<int *> vp;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    vp[i] = &v[i];
  return sum(vp);
}
```

But it doesn't seem quite right, does it?

Comment: I'd do the opposite. Use normal vector for summation, convert from pointer-based if necessary. This would have more performance if its normal vector. I mean, no need to add a layer of redirection if its just summation.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the standard algorithm library where the problem you see has a solution.

Most algorithms have some default behavior but often allow you to customize that behavior via functor parameters.

For your specific case the algorithm of choice is [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Because this algorithm already exists I can restrict to a rather simplified illustration here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T,typename R,typename F = std::plus<>>
R sum(const std::vector<T>& v,R init,F f = std::plus<>{})
{  
  for (auto& e : v) init = f(init,e);
  return init;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> x{1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int*> y;
    for (auto& e : x ) y.push_back(&e);

    std::cout << sum(x,0)  << "\n";
    std::cout << sum(y,0,[](auto a, auto b) {return a + *b;});

}
```

`std::plus` is a functor that adds two values. Because the return type may differ from the vectors element type an additional template parameter `R` is used. Similar to `std::accumulate` this is deduced from the initial value passed as parameter. When adding `int` the default `std::plus<>` is fine. When adding integers pointed to by pointers, the functor can add the accumulator with the dereferenced vector element. As already mentioned this is just a simple toy example. In the above link you can find a possible implementation of `std::accumulate` (which uses iterators rather than the container directly).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `sum` is really just a very simple example for a more complex function. The main issue here is can you have both functions without duplicating code nor copying one or the other vector

Comment: @ben I can only answer for the question you did post. For more complex algorithms the same works as well. Don't hardcode the operation you do on the elements, use some functor with a default and the caller can customize it

Answer (score 2):

With C++20 (or another ranges library), you can easily add or remove pointerness

```
template <std::ranges::range R, typename T>
concept range_of = requires std::same<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, T>;

template <range_of<int *> IntPointers>
int sum_pointers(IntPointers int_pointers)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int * p : int_pointers) result += *p;
    return result;
}

void call_adding_pointer()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    sum_pointers(v | std::ranges::views::transform([](int & i){ return &i; });
}
```

Or

```
template <range_of<int> Ints>
int sum(Ints ints)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : ints) result += i;
    return result;
}

void call_removing_pointer()
{
    std::vector<int *> v;
    sum(v | std::ranges::views::transform([](int * p){ return *p; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function template, which behaves differently for pointer and non-pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
auto sum(const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
    {
        typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type sum = 0;
        for (const auto & value : vec) sum += *value;
        return sum;
    }
    if constexpr (!std::is_pointer_v<T>)
    {
        T sum = 0;
        for (const auto & value : vec) sum += value;
        return sum;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> a{3, 4, 5, 8, 10};
    std::vector<int*> b{&a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4]};
    cout << sum(a) << endl;
    cout << sum(b) << endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sch3KovaK

You can move almost everything out of the `if constexpr` to reduce code duplication:

```
template <class T>
auto sum(const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type sum = 0;
    for (const auto & value : vec) 
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
            sum += *value;
        if constexpr (!std::is_pointer_v<T>)
            sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rvqK89sEK

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mch solution:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::array<double, 3> center(const std::vector<T> & particles)
{
    if (particles.empty())
        return {0, 0, 0};

    std::array<double, 3> cumsum = {0, 0, 0};

    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
    {
        for (const auto p : particles)
        {
            cumsum[0] += p->getX();
            cumsum[1] += p->getY();
            cumsum[2] += p->getZ();
        }
    }
    if constexpr (not std::is_pointer_v<T>)
    {
        for (const auto p : particles)
        {
            cumsum[0] += p.getX();
            cumsum[1] += p.getY();
            cumsum[2] += p.getZ();
        }
    }
    double f = 1.0 / particles.size();
    cumsum[0] *= f;
    cumsum[1] *= f;
    cumsum[2] *= f;
    return cumsum;
}
```

Much cleaner and more efficient solution using `std::invoke`:

```
std::array<double, 3> centroid(const std::vector<T> & particles)
{
    if (particles.empty())
        return {0, 0, 0};

    std::array<double, 3> cumsum{0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    for (auto && p : particles)
    {
        cumsum[0] += std::invoke(&topology::Particle::getX, p);
        cumsum[1] += std::invoke(&topology::Particle::getY, p);
        cumsum[2] += std::invoke(&topology::Particle::getZ, p);
    }

    double f = 1.0 / particles.size();
    cumsum[0] *= f;
    cumsum[1] *= f;
    cumsum[2] *= f;
    return cumsum;
}
```

Comment: `const auto p : particles` ==> `const auto &p : particles` to not make a copy of the elements.

Comment: yep... totally right

Comment: This is accumulate followed by dividing the result, you need `std::array<double, 3> plus(std::array<double, 3>, particle)` (and `particle *`)

Comment: *I would be definitely interested in how you would do it with a functor function.* here you go https://godbolt.org/z/xs76jdc99. (only the final division is missing) Its only what I wrote in the answer applied to `particle`s accumulating in an `array` rather than adding `int`s

Comment: btw it is completely fine to answer your own question, but if you post simplified code in the question then the answer should refer to that code, rather than to the not simplified code that you did not include in the quesiton. Perhaps this is what you were actually looking for, but based on your question nobody could have come up with this

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I posted the actual problem because I was very intersted in the solution you proposed but didn't quite understand how to adapt it to my problem. Both mch and caleth  got that it was more about not duplicating code or copying data rather than actually summing integers. But totally agreed that I could have phrase it more clearly. Thanks a lot, again

Comment: An alternative to the `if constexpr`'s would be to use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) - that also avoids having to duplicate the code into both expressions. [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/GrsKjcf91)